# Render JSF components accordingly to media queries

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, media-queries, omnifaces

I have based a project on http://www.initializr.com/ and it's working really well. Everything scales like I want it to but the problem left to solve seems to be what components to render. Now whenever possible I of course choose components that can scale but some things cant be solved like this. Either to much potential wasted for desktop users or the desktop users are to used to certain components.

**Goal:**
I am using primefaces and I would like to skip a panelgroup from rendering if the screen is to small. It would not suffice with `display:none` since it would bloat the request. Instead I want to use the rendered attribute.

Could it be a good idea to base rendered on media queries? My implementation would be like this:

A dummy div in my most overarching template and have all the conditional css classes on this div. For the first request I would then parse this div with javascript or probably jquery and save the found style in a backingbean. This bean would then be used as rendered="#{displayBean.wide}", rendered="#{displayBean.narrow}", rendered="#{displayBean.tooltip}".

`p:remoteCommand` or `o:commandScript` would be the glue. Then I would probably cache the whole result in a cookie or maybe using o:cache would suffice.

This way I can get a lot of information set and let the browser take care of it and make sure it's always synchronized between css style and rendered.

Is it good design? Any other ideas on how to solve a few conditional renderings between desktop friendly / handheld friendly components (such as tooltips, big navigational divs and such).